# Clean shutdown of the mongod process

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb run under Linux 6. I use the command db.shutdownServer() to close the database but the mongod process does not stop.
Stopping mongo directly with service mongod stop do a clean shutdown?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Proper ways to shutdown mongod is described in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes). They are:

> **Use shutdownServer()**
>   From the mongo shell
>   use admin
>   db.shutdownServer()
>
> **Use --shutdown**
>   From the Linux command line
>   mongod --shutdown
>
> **Use CTRL-C**
>   When running the mongod instance in interactive mode, issue Control-C
>
> **Use kill**
>   From the Linux command line
>   kill mongoProcessID
>   kill -2 mongodProcessID

So you need to figure out how `/etc/init.d/mongodb stop` actually stops the process on your Linux distribution. For example, on Debian it uses the wrapper which behaves similar to `killall` which is a proper method.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of mongodb, `mongod --shutdown` will work on linux system, but, on Mac, the `--shutdown` switch is not recognised. However, per the documentation, `Ctrl+C` will cleanly shutdown the db server. When you do a `Ctrl+C` on the same terminal where the db server is running, it initiates a dozen or so `signalProcessingThread` which indicates that the shutdown is proper and smooth. At the end, you can see that the process exits with `code:0`. Per the convention, `Ctrl+C` is awkward, but is clean, although not seemingly graceful.